# Why does a magnet arranged in a magnetic accelerator propogate a wheel forward?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, kinetic-theory, accelerator-physics

My question is related to an interesting video i saw on magnets. The link of the video is here https://youtu.be/iyv9GhaITNE , in this video at 1:52 of the video we see the wheel is moved forward but i do not understand why? The magnets are at equal distances and of equal height so shouldn't the wheel just be stuck in loop instead of moving forward. If in the arrangement the succeeding magnets were closer than the preceding one than the progression would be justified but here i don't get it.Can someone please help me out on this?